# Access delegated Gmail account to fetch labeled emails

Tags: google-apps-script

So I've been busy compiling a code that is able to fetch all threads with a specific label 1 from Gmail Inbox, and parse certain elements of the messages into a sheet, and then remove label1 and add label2.

That works fabolously, but i tried this with my "personal" gmail account.
I can't authorize the script to run on the delegated department's account.

Is there any workaround to this?

As far as i could find out, I can't really define the account in the code itself, and in the beginning of 2019 there was no possibility to do it.

Comment: You can use Gmail API for that purpose. But it will require some admin intervention

Comment: Thanks for your input shabnan. Do you know if that requires a lot of work from the admins or needs a lot of rights?

Comment: @HankSchrader how did you solve this issue? I have the same problem - trying to access Gmail labels of delegated accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to have a service account with domain-wide authority, as explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/delegate_settings), from that service account you can run your script. This has to be enabled by your admin, to do so they can use [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@Skaaptjop/access-gsuite-apis-on-your-domain-using-a-service-account-e2a8dbda287c)

Lastly, since you mentioned you're using Apps Script, [this tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20375-service-accounts-google-apps-script) will show you how to use the service account through Apps Script.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, Unfortunately that is probably out of the question. So I will have to find another way to extract the data. Have a nice day!